# Import external modules in typescript angular app

Tags: angularjs, typescript, browserify, commonjs

I am refactoring a large app to use commonjs instead of a gazzilion script tags. I have refactored all the parts where the main app (entry point) imports the different app modules, app modules entry file loads its controllers, service etc. and I am happy with the code.
I am also using tsconfig.json files property (which include tsd.d.ts with external dependencies typings) for reference resolution and both webstorm and vscode seem happy with the code as well.

I have not used any external module imports so far. Trying to compile/bundle my code either using tsc or browserify generates quite a few errors about not finding external modules eg. "Cannot find name 'angular'". So I thought fine, I will require angular in that file:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import {avatarModuleServices} from './services/module';
import {avatarModuleDirectives} from './directives/module';

import {AvatarProcessController} from './avatar-process-controller';
export var avatarModule = angular.module('cv.avatar', [
        avatarModuleServices.name,
        avatarModuleDirectives.name,
        'angularFileUpload'
    ])
    .controller(AvatarProcessController.className, AvatarProcessController);
```

but then I get error

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'angular'.

and I thought, it's probably because I am using bower to get angular and external imports probably look into node_modules directory. So I went ahead and installed angular through npm, but problem remains.

At this point what are my options for bundling my code along with external dependencies both from npm and bower?

btw I am using the latest version of everything (angular 1.4.8, tsc 1.7.3, browserify 12.0.1 etc)

Comment: Is the angular .d.ts referenced correctly in the tsd.d.ts file? in any case try including a reference to the angular d.ts directly preceding the import in the file you copied the example above from.

Comment: Yes angular.d.ts is included in tsd.d.ts. And resolution in multiple IDEs works fine through the use of tsconfig.json. I fail to see the point of both using tsconfig.json and the dreaded reference comments